# Join Table with extra column

Tags: oop, jpa

In my spring boot application I have user model, type model and user_type. Here a join table is created in the user model as user_type.

Model in maven project with jpa :

```
package com.example.pharmanic.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table( name = "users",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")
        })
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String password;

    **@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") ,
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")

    )**

    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String email, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

The join table user_role has two columns; user_id & role_id.
I want to add an extra column to user_role table to save more data relevant to user_role. A type String column should be added to the user_role table.

Comment: To do that you will have to model the JPA entity for the user_role table and treat it as one more table, instead of using the JoinTable annotation, you will have to use two JoinColumn annotations and establish the bidirectional relationships leaving something like ROLE - USER_ROLE - USER

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a `Map<Role, String>` with `@ElementCollection` and `@MapKeyJoinColumn`- the values of the map will then be mapped to a column in the join table. Not sure if that makes sense in you particular use case, though